Include another Word document in a Word document given a relative path
I have a file main.docx in which I want to include the content of another word file, snippet.docx. I have been following various suggestions on this (e.g. here {INCLUDETEXT} does not work with the relative path created with {filename} in word. {INCLUDEPICUTRE} works fine, though) and tried the INCLUDETEXT field code in conjunction with the FILENAME field code. The idea is to use the latter to figure out the absolute path of the current document, and then put together the result with a relative path to find the absolute path to snippet.docx.
An example looks like:
{ INCLUDETEXT "{ FILENAME \p}\\..\\snippet.docx" }

And this "works" to the extent that on saving main.docx, the nested FILENAME field code is replaced by its value. Is there a way of making this work?

Admittedly, the document folder would no longer be portable, but is that sufficient reason not to use the absolute path?

I think so in my case, as my real use case includes dozens of these cases - many main documents including a large number of different snippets.

see http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Is snippet.docx a file in the local file system? Could the total length of the path name exceed a limit? (Can't remember the details, could be 255 characters).

@CharlesKenyon: I followed that approach, and it does not work in Office 2016 because once I save the document containing the complex field code above, Office will replace the nested FILENAME field code by its value (ie. the path of the document).

I thought I'd managed to replicate this yesterday, but cannot. I don't remember anything like this in any version of Word, for this field type. OTOH this behaviour is unavoidable in LINK fields with nested fields, and can also  occur in HYPERLINK fields with nested fields.  I wonder if this problem has been introduced in a very new update of Word?

That code works fine for me in the current Office 365 Word. For example, with two .docx files in the same folder:
{ INCLUDETEXT  "{ FILENAME  \p }\\..\\snippet.docx"  }

Make sure that each set of braces { } is an actual field object, and not just text (selecting just one curly brace should highlight the entire field). Once everything is added, make sure to use Update Field to force it to re-resolve the target filename.

Thank you for your answer! I am using Office 2016, and the field code work for m as well. The issue is that on save, the inner field code (FILENAME) is replaced completely by the resolved path.

@rugermini In 365 Word, if I try selecting that path, I see it is still a field object, and not just text (press Shift+F9 with it selected to show its field codes again). If I use "Update Field" again in a new location, the path updates. I can't be sure about 2016
